# Lazy loading on gantt charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, lazy-loading, gantt-chart

I'm trying to show huge series of work breakdown structure data from an API into GanttChart so it increase page loading time and becomes unresponsive sometimes. I think one of the solutions could be get data in lazy mood. I googled it and found this link on GitHub:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14232

unfortunately I'm new in HighCharts and JavaScript and it seems it doesn't works or maybe I can't figure out how it works. The ideal scenario would be fetch child tasks within a series every time the parent is expanded.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Related (unanswered) question: [HighCharts Gantt takes long time to load when it has huge series data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73275399/high-chart-gant-chart-takes-long-time-to-load-when-it-has-huge-series-data) Also see: [Highcharts Stock Demos › 1.7 million points with async loading](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/lazy-loading)

Comment: Thanks @Yogi, Actually I checked this two links before, the first one as you said is unanswered and the other I couldn't match it with GanttChart because fetching data should be occurred on expanding a parent node event.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a `click` event on `label` and `labelIcon` SVG elements:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const chart = this;
        const ticks = chart.yAxis[0].ticks;
                
        for (let key in ticks) {
          if (ticks[key].treeGrid.labelIcon) {
            [ticks[key].label, ticks[key].treeGrid.labelIcon].forEach(
              element => element.on('click', () => handleLabelClick(ticks[key]))
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But unfortunately, the stairs begin next. Currently, Highcharts `gantt` charts dont't play well with dynamic data, mostly because of [this reported bug](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16664). The only way for now, but not very optimal, seems to be creating a new chart with partial data on each expand action.

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c8whg3kv/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek. It seems that I should change to another components like `DevExtreme` ...